# How to delete a managed secret in Azure Key Vault?

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I have an Azure Key Vault which manages some storage account access keys. As such, I've created a SAS definition as a secret which is managed by the vault. However, it's no longer needed and I'd like to remove it.

When I use the CLI with `az keyvault secret delete` I get the folowing error message:

`Operation "delete" is not allowed as this object's lifetime is managed by Key Vault.`

Is there any way I can remove the secret while still allowing Key Vault to manage the storage account access key?

Comment: A "managed" secret is a secret that backs storage account key. It can't directly be mutated - for example, if you want to delete it, then you should instead delete the corresponding storage account key.

Comment: If you delete it, it's not managed by Key Vault.

Comment: With "delete the corresponding storage account key" I mean az command az keyvault storage remove --name MyStorageAccount --vault-name MyVault